# How do I have sphinx perform a star search in the middle of a string?

Tags: sphinx

For example, searching for the word cat, I would want to match words with #*cat*.  I already have the hash tag indexing setup, and I have sphinx setup for star searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not well documented and I've never tried it myself, but a post here: 
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9847

from a Sphinx developer, suggests that using a plain index, and dict=keywords, would allow wildcard, so could search

```
#%cat*
```

For some reason % seems to be used as the wildcard in the middle of a string.